# A collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that is not a topology

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that the collection of sets of the form: $$\{(-\infty, x] : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ together with the empty set and $\mathbb{R}$, is not a topology for $\mathbb{R}$. But if I take the infinite union of sets of the form $\{(-\infty, x] : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, this is not itself a set of the form $\{(-\infty, y] : y \in \mathbb{R}\}$, where $y$ is the maximum of all $x$? And if I take the finite intersection of this sets, this is not again, a set of the form $\{(-\infty, x] : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, where $x= \text{min}(x_1,...,x_n)$?

Comment: The infinite union and the infinite intersection are not of the form.  But the finite intersection and finite unions are.  And what exactly is your question?

Comment: "Why this is not a topology?" But questioning like this, it seems to me that I'm just copying the problem enunciate. I like to say what I tried, and where I stopped.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, this isn't a topology.
Consider a sequence of sets $A_n = (-\infty, -1/n]$.
The union of all the $A_n$'s equals
$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n = (-\infty, 0)$$
which is not of the form $(-\infty, x]$ because $0$ is not included in the above interval.
Therefore, the collection you described does not satisfy the "infinite union" axiom of topology.

Answer (score 1):

Take the union $$\bigcup_{x<y} (-\infty,x],$$ this is $(-\infty,y)$ which is not in your collection of open sets.